# in Laravel-8 Captcha starting on server problem

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, captcha

How can i resolve this problem about Mews Captcha?

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
                                                         
  Class 'Mews\Captcha\CaptchaServiceProvider' not found
```

Comment: try deleting `vendor` and running `composer install` again

Comment: I did that but nothing is happen. In local it is working but when I deploy with git its giving error.

Comment: nothing meaning nothing gets installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mews Captcha not installed or configured properly.
Please follow below steps:

composer require mews/captcha

If all goes well,Then

Find the providers key in config/app.php and register the Captcha Service Provider.

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    'Mews\Captcha\CaptchaServiceProvider',
]
```

To use your own settings, publish config.

$ php artisan vendor:publish

config/captcha.php

```
return [
    'default'   => [
        'length'    => 5,
        'width'     => 120,
        'height'    => 36,
        'quality'   => 90,
        'math'      => true,  //Enable Math Captcha
        'expire'    => 60,    //Stateless/API captcha expiration
    ],    
];
```

For more details

[mewebstudio captcha details](https://github.com/mewebstudio/captcha)

Comment: Thanks resolved problem thanks of this steps

Comment: @CansuKoç Please mark my solution as complete and up the vote